# Batch file - counting number of lines

Tags: batch-file

I am using below BATCH script to count number of lines

`Find /V /C "" < c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\123.txt  >> lines.log`

Is it possible to get info in a dialog / message box (info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ok?

```
@echo off

set "file_to_check=./test.xml"

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('Find /V /C "" ^< "%file_to_check%"') do (
    set "line_count=%%#"
)

::echo %line_count%

msg "%username%" "%line_count%"
```

or:

```
@echo off

set "file_to_check=./test.xml"

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('Find /V /C "" ^< "%file_to_check%"') do (
    set "line_count=%%#"
)

::echo %line_count%

::msg "%username%" "%line_count%"

mshta "about:Lines of the %file_to_check% are <p> %line_count%"
```

Comment: what is `mshta` I cannot fin documentation about it and I want to learn

Comment: @SNR is the internet explorer with an access to the file system and all the activeX objects. In this [topic](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5311) you can find some interesting tricks

Comment: @SNR - as a documentation you can use this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms536495(v%3Dvs.85)

Comment: Ah, dostips. Nice! Thanks!

Comment: This helped me set up a Windows batch file to count number of instances of a certain process over time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To display a message box from `cmd` we will have to use a `vbs` and execute it from `wscript` instead of `cscript`. This will execute a windows application instead of a console application. Then, using `.Echo()` we will be able to make a message box pop up.

From the command line,

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G  IN ('find /v /c "" ^< c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\123.txt') do ( 
set /a counter = %G 
)

echo >%temp%\msgbox.vbs Wscript.echo("Total count of lines: %counter%")

Wscript %Temp%\msgbox.vbs
```

Here `counter` will remain as an environment variable (`set counter=` to erase it). I suggest doing it from a batch file instead,

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G  IN ('find /v /c "" ^< c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\123.txt') do ( set /a counter = %%G )    

echo >%temp%\msgbox.vbs Wscript.echo("Total count of lines: !counter!")

Wscript %Temp%\msgbox.vbs

exit /B
```